# Compress all Folders in FolderA to Folder B without "backups"

Tags: bash, debian

i got a small Question.

I want to compress all Folders in 
/etc/nginx/html/ (there are the website folders)
into 
/etc/nginx/html/backups/

Now you see:
The folder "backups" is in the same folder like "Website1" and "Website2"
I dont want compress the folder "backups"

I try this:

```
cd $PATH_TO_WEBFOLDER

folders=`for i in $(ls -d */ | grep -Ev "(backups)"); do echo ${i%%/}; done`
for ftp in $folders; do
  tar -cvvzf $ftp-$datum.tar.gz *
done
```

But it dosent work.
Then i try this:

```
PATH_TO_WEBFOLDER="/etc/nginx/html"
datum=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
BACKUP_PATH="/etc/nginx/html/backups/$datum"


# make absolute and add dir
backup_path="$(readlink -f "$backup_path")/FTPBACKUP"
cd $PATH_TO_WEBFOLDER

for d in */; do
  d="${d%/}" # strip trailing slash

  if [ -n "${d##*(backup)*}" ]; then
    tar cvvzf "$backup_path/$d-$datum.tgz" "$d" 
  fi
done
```

But it also not working :/

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution seems to be using tar to exclude a folder:

`tar --exclude=./backups/ -cvvzf $ftp-$datum.tar.gz *`

This should be pretty straightforward.
I found on my system that --exclude had to be right after the tar command.